# Where condition with several OR

Tags: sql, oracle

```
where cdc_date_debut is null
   or cdc_date_fin   is null
   or (select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY') from dual)
          between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin
   or (select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY') from dual)
          not between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin
```

My problem is that I have case where the two or are true: today date between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin and today date  not between cdc_date_debut

In this case I want take only today date between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin.

thank for all help

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: `(select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY') from dual)` makes no sense whatsoever. Just use: `or sysdate between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin`

Comment: Unless I am missing something big your 2 SELECT BETWEEN make no sense either, because they are exact opposites. So you end up with something like "_OR this = true OR this = false_" which is the same as not  specifying anything. We can't answer your question

Comment: Just think about your last two clauses. SYSDATE must either be between the two dates or NOT be between the two dates. That doesn't sound very limiting does it. This sort of thing usually means you need to have a think about the logic and what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case I want take only today date between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin.

Then just delete the other case:

```
where cdc_date_debut is null
   or cdc_date_fin   is null
   or SYSDATE between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin
```

Your filter:

```
(select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY') from dual) between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin
```

Does not make sense. First, you do not need the sub-query, so it can immediately be simplified to:

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY') between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin
```

Then considering the data types you have

```
String between Date and Date
```

So Oracle will do one of two things:

1. Cast the dates to strings and your query becomes `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY') between TO_CHAR( cdc_date_debut ) and TO_CHAR( cdc_date_fin )`. Oracle will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model for these implicit casts (which brings its own issues that I'll consider in the second option) and then `BETWEEN` will use a string comparison... `'12/01/1970' BETWEEN '01/10/2017' AND '13/01/2000'` will return true using a string comparison (since `12` is between `01` and `13`) even though the first date is not between the latter two and the start of the between range is after then end...
2. Cast the string back to a date and your query becomes `TO_DATE( TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY') ) between cdc_date_debut and cdc_date_fin` and, again, Oracle will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model for this implicit cast and this will only work as you expect if it is also `'DD/MM/YY'` - if it is `'DD/MM/YYYY'` then all your dates will be re-cast to the 1st century AD; if it is `'MM/DD/YY'` then your days and months will be swapped (if it does not just throw an exception); and there are various other combinations of wrongness. To make matters more interesting, the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter so it can be different per user and the user can change it mid-session so the query could work for you but not for other users with different settings.

The conclusion is - do not cast your date to a string and use it in a comparison. Just leave it as a date.